# Request Sessions return FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, session, symfony

i'm working with symfony and trying to set and get session variable to pass trough a twig template.

I tryied the way is in the symfony example:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('name', 'Drak');
$session->get('name');
```

Twig:

```
{{ app.session.get('balance') }}
```

Returns this error message:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set).")

I check my php.ini and the sessions doesn't start automatycally, also there is no other session live.

I tried this way too:

```
   $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
// We store an attribute
        $session->set('FrenchTouch', 'Julian');
// in another controller for another request, we retrieve the value of this attribute
        $value = $session->get('FrenchTouch');
        print_r(array($value));
```

But returns this other error:

FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Comment: According to Symfony docs, `a session will start on demand`.  Try getting rid of the line `$session->start();`

Comment: Already tried and get the following error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set).")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did find the answer,

The problem wasn't in the way to get/set the session, the issue comes because i'm passing the info trough controllers and i was using a non-native symfony way. The correct way to pass info in controllers is:

```
$response = $this->forward('YourBundle:YourController:YourAction', array(
 'user'=>$user
));
return $response;
```

And then in the other controller set the sessions and render the template.

Answer (score 2):

Get the session from the container

```
$session = $this->container->get('session');
```

Comment: same thing: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in UserController.php line 29:

$session = $this->container->get('session');
        $session->set('name', 'Sensorario');
        $test = $session->get('name');
        print_r($test);

Comment: Do you extend the framework controller of injected the container?

Comment: I was creating a new instances from another controller, i fixed it injecting the container.